# Regex Expression for textfield

Tags: regex

I want a regix format that Must be alphabets and special characters (like space, `‘`, `-`) but numeric value should not be taken.

I tried with this expression `/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/` but it treats space as special character.

Please Help.

Comment: Yours should work already... What do you mean by *space as special character*?

Comment: what is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: I tried with different expressions but all failed. I tried with this "^[A_ZA-z,‘,-]+$" but it's not allowing space.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[a-zA-Z\s\-\'\"]*$/
```

use this.

This will contain any alphabet([upper/lower]case)
,space,
hiphen,
",
'

**update**

If you are using it inside NSPredicate
then make sure that you put the `-` in the end, as it throws error.
Move it to the end of the sequence to be the last character before the closing square bracket `]`.

like this `[a-zA-Z '"-]`

Comment: The app crashed with this reason: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching, reason: Can't open pattern U_REGEX_INVALID_RANGE (string dhvani puar, pattern /^[a-zA-Zs-'"]*$/, case 0, canon 0)'

Comment: which reason ? and what app ?

Comment: do you escaping characters, I have used \s not s , s is for literal match with s, while \s is for space and also escape other chars as well

Comment: @user3271123 are you using predicate ?

Comment: @user3271123 did you try my updated solution or can you include the piece of code you are using in NSpredicate

Comment: +(BOOL)isCharacter:(NSString*)inputString{
//    NSRegularExpression *rang = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"/^[a-zA-Z\\s\\-\'\"-]*$/" options:0 error:nil];
    NSString *characterRegex = @"/^[a-zA-Z\\s\\-\'\"-]*$/";
    NSPredicate *characterTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",characterRegex];
    return [characterTest evaluateWithObject:inputString];
}

Comment: I'm writing this but with this it's not even allowing to enter any character

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
\b[a-zA-Z \-\']+\b
```

http://regex101.com/r/oQ5nU9

Comment: `\b` is used for word endings only it will still match the parts which are matching , the only way you can make it correct is by using `^` and `$` anchors

Comment: really? I check the on the regexp101.com (I updated link) and it seems to work - is it a problem of the webpage?

Comment: its not the problem of regex101, its problem of your regex

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the alphabets and space, `'` and `-` then:

```
/^[-a-zA-Z\s\']+$/
```

Notice the `+` from above instead of `*`. If you use `*` then it will match with empty string, where the `+` sign means to have at least one character in your input.

Now, if you want to match any alphabets with any special characters(not only those three which are mentioned), then I'll just you to use this one:

```
/^\D+$/
```

It means any characters other than digits!

Answer (score 0):

You can use it defiantly work it

```
[a-zA-Z._^%$#!~@,-]+
```

this code work fine you can try it....

Answer (score 0):

//Use this for allowing space as we all as other special character.

@"[a-zA-Z\\s\\-\\'\\"]"

//Following link will be help for further.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/30288/nsregularexpression-tutorial-and-cheat-sheet

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.. I finally resolved it with this

NSString *characterRegex = @"^(\s*[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\-\+\s]\s*[a-zA-Z])?[a-zA-Z]*)\s*)+$";
    NSPredicate *characterTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",characterRegex];
    return [characterTest evaluateWithObject:inputString];